# Excel If Not Failing to exit Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following `Do` with a nested `If Not` statement:

```
Do
        Set i = SrchRng.Find("#609532", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not i Is Nothing Then i.EntireRow.Copy
            BBsheet.Activate
            nextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Cells(nextRow, 1).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            srcBook.Activate
            i.EntireRow.Delete
    Loop While Not i Is Nothing
```

This functions properly but it is failing to exit the loop when it should.  When I step through it, it grabs the `If Not i` and skips over the copy command, but still steps through the lines below and fails on the `Selection.PasteSpecial`.  I can not seem to get it to skip over those and move on to the next `Do`.  The following works, but I need to copy before the delete:

```
Do
        Set i = SrchRng.Find("#609532", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not i Is Nothing Then i.EntireRow.Delete
    Loop While Not i Is Nothing
```

How do I get the loop to register that "#609532" no longer exists and move on to the next loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `If .. Then .. End If` statement instead `If ... Then ..`:

```
Do
    Set i = SrchRng.Find("#609532", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not i Is Nothing Then 
        i.EntireRow.Copy
        BBsheet.Activate
        nextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Cells(nextRow, 1).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        srcBook.Activate
        i.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Loop While Not i Is Nothing
```

and it's better to avoid `Select` and `Activate` statements:

```
Do
    Set i = SrchRng.Find("#609532", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not i Is Nothing Then
        i.EntireRow.Copy
        With BBsheet
            nextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Cells(nextRow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
        End With
        i.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Loop While Not i Is Nothing
```

Comment: Damn! Too Late... I will have to discard my answer :D BTW no need of `.Activate` :)

Comment: Or `.Select` [INTERESTING READ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I've just updated answer with code avoiding `Select` and `Activate` statements

Comment: @SiddharthRout, and I should save your "Interesting Read" link for the future answers:)

Comment: That's great info, and I've heard the whole don't use `.Activate` argument before, but your second block of code starts pasting on line 998 of the excel sheet.  Any idea how to start at the top of that sheet without using `.Activate`?

Comment: @Benjooster, Have you used last code (my answer was updated 17 min ago)?. As I see, second block of code should do the same as first one. You tries to paste values using `nextRow` variable, which is defined as follows: `nextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1`. This line means that   `nextRow` will be equal to the first _empty_ row in column 'A'. If code pastes values starting from 998 line, it means that your `A997` cell not empty

Comment: @simoco Yes that was my assumption as well.  Clearing the sheet didn't resolve the issue, and even more confusing the first block of code starts at Row 2.

Comment: @Benjooster, have you use this line of code `nextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1` or this one `nextRow = Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1` (note that there is no `.` before `Cells`)?

Comment: @simoco Totally missed that.  Thanks.